# How to Alter Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL How to Alter Constraint

Below is 1 of my constraint

```
CONSTRAINT ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(ActiveProgCode) REFERENCES PROGRAM(ActiveProgCode),
```

I want to add in

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

to the constraint above.

How do i alter that existing constraint ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1 and add

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

to constraint ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1

Consider ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1 is at Table ACTIVEPROG

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can not alter constraints ever but you can drop them and then recreate.

Have look on this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP CONSTRAINT ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1;
```

and then recreate it with `ON DELETE CASCADE` like this

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
add CONSTRAINT ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(ActiveProgCode) REFERENCES PROGRAM(ActiveProgCode)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

hope this help

Comment: you can enable/disable constraints.

Comment: @FlorinGhita, yes we can enable/disable...............Sometimes it's useful to disable one or more constraints on a table, do something significant, and then re-enable the constaint(s) after you're done. This is most often done to improve performance during a bulk load operation.

Comment: adding IF EXISTS makes sure you can run this always and make sure the key always exists , so that it does not depend on a certain order.

Answer (score 20):

No. We cannot alter the constraint, only thing we can do is drop and recreate it

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] DROP CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINTNAME]
```

> Foreign Key Constraint

```
Alter Table Table1 Add Constraint [CONSTRAINTNAME] Foreign Key (Column) References Table2 (Column) On Update Cascade On Delete Cascade
```

> Primary Key constraint

```
Alter Table Table add constraint [Primary Key] Primary key(Column1,Column2,.....)
```

Comment: It's true that what the OP wants is not possible, but why do you post a link to a SQL Server site for a question that is tagged Oracle?