# mysql change constraint name, how?

Tags: mysql, constraints, rename

```
create table Foo(
 userId bigint(20) not null,
 KEY `Foo_userId` (`userId`),
 CONSTRAINT `Foo_userId` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `User` (`id`)
);
```

How to change the Key/constraint name from Foo_userId to Bar_userId, just change names only. I know that they can be dropped first, then re-create them. I am looking for a simple way like

```
alter table Foo rename KEY Foo_userId Bar_userId;
alter table Foo rename CONSTRAINT Foo_userId Bar_userId;
```

Is there anything like this in mysql? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the constraint name or properties you can delete the old foreign key constraint and add a new one. This is the only solution that it really worked for me.

```
alter table FOO 
drop foreign key Foo_userId,
add constraint Bar_userId foreign key (`userId`) references`User` (`id`)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint) is another answer that helped me.