# Dropping and adding a constraint in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to drop and add a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Entity] DROP  CONSTRAINT [x_UpdateDate1]  
-- default value 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Entity] ADD CONSTRAINT [x_UpdateDate1]  
                           DEFAULT ([dbo].[GETSYSTEMDATE]()) 
                           FOR [CreateDate]
```

I want to find the alternative for this. As dropping and adding a constraint is not advisable. Is there any better way to handle

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Alter Constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint). Short answer, you can't alter a constraint, only drop it and add it again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You cannot alter a constraint, you need to drop it and then recreate it just as you did.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no other way than to drop and re-create constraints ([check also sqlauthority.com blog entry](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/24/sql-server-how-to-alter-constraint/))

Answer (score -2):

You can disable constraints with:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

and then turn them back on with:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all
```

of course this SQL turns off ALL constraints on the table but you can specify an individual constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl NOCHECK CONSTRAINT Constraint1
```

Comment: What does this has to do with the question asked?

Comment: What do you think niru is trying to accomplish?  When you read his question with this thought in mind, then it seems quite clear.  This is a solution to a problem that would cause someone to ask what niru asked.  Perhaps what he finds here may solve his problem.

Comment: Op asked how to alter a constraint to add a default value to it. I don't see anything that could help him/her in this answer

Comment: I can explain the solution, I cannot be responsible to make you understand it.

Comment: Then please, do explain how this would add a default value to the constraint

Comment: There are two reasons that you would not want to drop/add a constraint.  1. you do not have rights and 2. the data table is so large that the demands to accomplish this are unacceptable.  In the event that this question is limited to a "default" constraint as given as an example then disabling the constraint will have no effect.  But in the event where you want to remove(disable) a constraint for a massive data load or other task that will tax your server, (because the boss asks for it this way) the above has served me well.