# How to modify a constraint on a SQL Server table from c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to modify a constraint on a SQL Server table from C# code. Is it possible to do?

Please help.

Here is a sample code for update that I use.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{ 
      command.CommandText = "UPDATE Student(LastName, FirstName, Address, City) 
                             VALUES(@ln, @fn, @add, @cit) WHERE LastName='" + lastName + "' AND FirstName='" +  firstName+"'";
      connection.Open();

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: yes it's possible, do you have any existing code to connect to the sql?

Comment: Why do you want to modify your constraints from C#? How often are you modifying these constraints?

Comment: You execute commands to DROP then reCREATE it; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint

Comment: Is there a problem with your sample? Does it work?

Comment: That code doesn't have anything to do with a constraint. You are simply updating the table. And your code is wide open to sql injection. Move the values to parameters.

Comment: I'm actually migrating a accessdb to sql..in access for a column there is a disallow zero length constraint. when I enter space for that column, MS Access allows .but the same doesn't work post migration.this is going to be a one time activity post migration

Comment: If it is for migration then just run the script to alter you constraint in SSMS.

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement is all wrong - it should be `UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET Col1 = Value1, Col2 = Value2 .... WHERE (condition)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var removeConstraint = "ALTER TABLE Customer DROP CONSTRAINT Con_First;";
var createConstraint = "ALTER TABLE Customer ADD CONSTRAINT Con_First UNIQUE (Address);";
var removeConstraintCmd = new SqlCommand(removeConstraint, conn);
removeConstraintCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var createConstraintCmd = new SqlCommand(createConstraint, conn);
createConstraintCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

NOTE: `conn` is your connection

The script strings (top two variables) will be what you need to change but, in summary, you drop the constrain then recreate it.

As a side note, I'd be curious to see why you want to do this. You may have problems in your overall approach as this is not something typically done from ADO .net (depending on your scenario of course).