# How to change a constraint name and schema on Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-schema, sp-rename

I just moved my `Member` table from `MRK` schema to `GNR`.

I previously had the script below to set its primary key:

```
If not Exists (select 1 
               from sys.objects 
               where name = 'PK_MRK_Member'
              )
        ALTER TABLE      [MRK].[Member] 
        ADD   CONSTRAINT [PK_MRK_Member] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
          [MemberID] ASC
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

How do I change the name AND the schema of the defined constraint now?

I tried `exec sp_rename 'PK_MRK_Member', 'PK_GNR_Member', 'INDEX'` for changing the name, but get this error:

`Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (INDEX) is wrong.`

P.S.: I cannot drop the table and/or the PK constraint and create them again since they PK is already in use by other tables.

Comment: you cannot alter constraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint

Comment: Thanks for the help @PrasanthVJ and Jeroen Mostert 
I guess I will give up on that :)

Comment: In general, you cannot alter a constraint. But this case is special -- although the primary key is a constraint, the underlying index _can_ be renamed, per @vladimir-semashkin below.

Answer (score 3):

As  I see your first parameter is wrong for procedure `sp_rename`. When you rename an index you should specify the schema and table as well as index name.
Check this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33083/rename-primary-key-constraint-on-azure) for example

Comment: In the code above, the statement that should do the rename is `exec sp_rename 'GNR.Member.PK_MRK_Member', 'PK_GNR_Member', 'INDEX'`. The schema of the index is always that of its parent table, so there's no need to rename that separately.