# Migrating room database in android

Tags: java, android

I just updated my database in android and can't get an app to migrate.

The change I made is that I added (`autoGenerate = true`) to my `@PrimaryKey`

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
```

I tried a whole lot of things, but I cannot get the migration to work.

The problem arises in my AppDatabase class where i inserted following code:

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE inventory");
    }
};
```

The `ALTER TABLE` inventory isn't the right command but I cannot figure out what is

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is incorrect `ALTER TABLE inventory`. You did not specify what is going to be changed on the table.

For example: `ALTER TABLE inventory ADD name TEXT` that means there is a new column `name` in type `TEXT` to be added in the table `inventory`.

While your case is a constraint change, and there is no way to alter constraint. 
But you can drop the constraint and add it again.

Please read the answer here:
[How to Alter Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)