# Select the column names that can not be null

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to modify the "not null" property for the columns that has this property set on.

Is is possible to get the column names to do that and then run "ALTER TABLE..." to modify to "null" so the value of the columns will be optional?

Comment: modify them to what?

Comment: modify them to "null", so the value of the columns will be optional. I modified my question. Thanks @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table column information from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html).

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA='yourdb' and is_nullable='NO'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify all the columns to be changed and their attributes from information_schema.columns. so

```
select concat(
'Alter table ',
table_name,
' modify column ',
column_name,' ',
column_type,
';'
)
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` where table_schema = 'sandbox' and is_nullable = 'no'
```

will generate a bunch of alter statements.

You should change sandbox to the schema you are interested in.

NOTE I haven't tested this thoroughly so beware

Answer (score -1):

You can't Alter the `constraint` but you can delete it then recreate it.

*Follow These steps and your problem will be fixed;*

*First, Drop your constraint:*

```
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP CONSTRAINT ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1;
```

*Then, Recreate it:*

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
add CONSTRAINT ACTIVEPROG_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(ActiveProgCode) REFERENCES PROGRAM(ActiveProgCode)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

***Reference:***

[How to Alter Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244889/how-to-alter-constraint)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know the name of the columns to alter first.

Comment: @ziiweb what do you mean by the name of the column you want to alter ?

Comment: @ziiweb recheck the answer