# Modify a constraint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl

Can we modify constraints using "MODIFY" keyword in SQL?

Comment: not possible, check this out -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861146/can-you-replace-or-update-a-sql-constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Create a new constraint first and then drop the old one.